# PHP Submit form and get xml generated on the page

Tags: php, xml, post

Here is what I need to do:

1. submit post form with some hidden fields
2. on the 'action' page xlm is generated
3. get the xml generated there using php

and then I will parce xml in order to get some info.

I tried to do it using $.post function but I cannot get the xml somewhy.

```
$.post(
                'https://..',
                {
                    method : 'result',
                    payee_id : \"{$obj->payee_id}\",
                    login : \"{$obj->login}\",
                    password : \"{$obj->password}\",
                    shop_order_number : \"{$obj->shopOrderNumber}\",
                    status : 'PAYED',
                },
                function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            );
```

and this code doesn't work.

Comment: Is your problem related to PHP or jQuery or what?

Comment: At the moment problem is about jQuery, but I would like to find the way to solve the problem using php

Comment: Why don't you do a normal submission from the web page to your PHP script, i mean why do you need jQuery to sibmit the form?

Comment: Because I need to parse the xml from the web site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
$("#myForm").ajaxSubmit({url: 'my_script.php', type: 'post'})
```

OR

```
$("#myForm").ajaxForm({url: 'my_script.php', type: 'post'})
```

To submit AJAX forms using jQuery.

Hope this would solve the form POSTing problem you got.